# VBA Event handler for wookrsheet_beforedoublelcick

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i am trying to write up a tool so that when i double click any cell on column a it will populate in column b. Column a will have many different rows of different string and i want to be able to simply double click on any cell to have it populated on column b.

i.e; i would click on cell a1,a5,a8, a111 and these 4 cells clicked will appear on column b1, b2,b3,b4

I know that i am missing a loop, but i cant seem to figure out where i am suppose to put it

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)

x = 1


sel = Target.Value

Cells(x, 2).Value = sel

x = x + 1

Cancel = False

End Sub
```

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a loop:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim rgOut as Range
If Target.Column = 1 then
Set rgOut = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
if len(rgOut.formula) <> 0 then set rgOut = rgOut.Offset(1)

rgOut.Value = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you Rory for your help.  Could you kindly explain to me the line 5 on what you did there?

Comment: I test if the cell in question is blank (should only happen for the first row) and if not, go one row down.